# Did Abraham and Sarah say a blessing on hearing a good news about their future heir?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, blessing, abraham, vayera

IIRC, one says a Brachah of "Hatov veha-Meitiv" on hearing good news (source needed).

When the angels came to inform Abraham and Sara of giving birth to Isaac in exactly one year, did they say a blessing?

Comment: I am not sure this is called 'good' news before the child is born. If someone is expecting you dont make a brocho. however long you have waited.

Comment: The brocha is made upon hearing that something good has already happened. See Shulchan Aruch O.C. 222 with commentaries.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%91_%D7%96 "ויבן שם מזבח" - על בשורת הזרע ועל בשורת א"י

Comment: @Jay Very interesting, make it an answer. Although it contradicts Grapke's findings.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE  Very interesting, make it an answer. Although it contradicts Jay's findings.

Comment: Neither contradicts the other. My comment speaks to the requirements for a very specific brocha "Hatov veha-Meitiv". The other source is about other forms of gratitude.

Answer (score 1):

As per above discussion, we have contradictory sources quoted by @Jay and myself.

Apparently a resolution could be that there is a difference between knowing (thinking) something will happen in the future and *nevuah*.

So that if the announcement is via *nevuah* then you can praise Hashem for the good tidings now, because the imminent now becomes irreversible.